# Group pattern using parenthesis

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a very long list of data. Below is a simplified version

```
data = {junk1, textHeader, moveTo, text, moveTo, text, junk2, 
  textHeader, moveTo, text, junk3}
```

I want to extract sequences that start with **textHeader** followed with **moveTo**, **text** and group them.

The result I desire from the above data is

```
{{textHeader, moveTo, text, moveTo, text}, {textHeader, moveTo, text}}
```

I can get the first group as follows:

```
Cases[{data}, {__, head : textHeader, move : moveTo, tex : text, __} :> {head, move, tex}]
```

which results in

```
{{textHeader, moveTo, text}}
```

In order to get multiple occurrences of **moveTo** and **text** I tried:

```
Cases[{data}, {__, head : textHeader, 
   moveNtext : (moveTo, text) .., __} :> {head, moveNtext}]
```

but I get an error message that says

*Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "moveTo,text)".*

In addition to overcoming this problem I am only getting out one group and for this case there should be two groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases):

```
SequenceCases[
    data,
    {textHeader, s:PatternSequence[moveTo, text]..} -> {textHeader, s}
]
```

> {{textHeader, moveTo, text, moveTo, text}, {textHeader, moveTo, text}}

Comment: Got it. `SequenceCases` rather than `Sequence` and `PatternSequence` rather than parenthesis. Thanks Carl.